# Swift - Container view not resizing on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, orientation

I saw several questions related to this issue, but no answers applicable to my case.

I have a view controller (sampleVC) inside a container (sampleContainer) that loads perfectly in whichever position you start with, but that won't resize after changing from landscape to portrait or vice-versa.

In my view controller I have:

```
    func addSampleVC() {
        self.addChild(self.sampleVC)
        self.sampleVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        self.sampleContainer.addSubview(self.sampleVC.view)
        self.addSampleConstraints()
    }

   func addSampleConstraints() {
        sampleContainer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: -20, width: sampleContainer.bounds.width, height: sampleContainer.bounds.height)
        sampleVC.view.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sampleContainer.bounds.width * 0.94, height: sampleContainer.bounds.height)
        sampleVC.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        sampleContainer.clipsToBounds = true

        NSLayoutConstraint.constrain(view: sampleVC.view, containerView: sampleContainer)
    }
```

The function addSampleVC is called from viewDidLoad. Based on other answers, I tried getting the updated container bounds inside viewWillTransition and then calling setNeedsLayout and setNeedsUpdate, but I must be missing something, because nothing seems to work. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dealt once with view containers, so I'll try to help you as best I can.

You can choose to use auto-layout or "manual" layout (aka auto resizing constraints). In your code, inside the addSampleConstraints, the left anchor statement in line 3 will be ignored since auto layout was not explicitly set.

1. Manual layout:

```
    func addSampleVC() {
        self.addChild(self.sampleVC)
        self.sampleContainer.addSubview(self.sampleVC.view)
        self.addSampleConstraints()
        self.sampleVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

   func addSampleConstraints() {
        sampleContainer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: -20, width: sampleContainer.bounds.width, height: sampleContainer.bounds.height)
        sampleVC.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        sampleVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sampleContainer.bounds.width * 0.94, height: sampleContainer.bounds.height)
        sampleContainer.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

2. Auto layout (first function is the same as in 1.):

```
   func addSampleConstraints() {
        sampleContainer.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // Setting Auto layout
        sampleVC.view.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // Setting Auto layout
        sampleVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
        sampleVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        sampleVC.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleContainer.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.94).isActive = true
        sampleVC.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        sampleContainer.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```